# how do I copy these files with access denied?

Tags: windows-7, security

I had to reformat my computer but I backed up all my data onto a hard drive. Now some of the files that I backed up are getting access denied when I try to put them back onto the new OS. How do I get complete control and no longer get access denied? I have already gone through the permissions and selected full control but I still get access denied.

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs after a clean installation, due to SID changes. Taking ownership of those folders/files should grant you full access. Detailed instructions are available in the following Microsoft article page.

[Take Ownership of a File or Folder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc753659.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: It would be helpful if you went into detail how to take ownership of the files and folders.